# Could not load native library jni_latinime.so Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

It gives an error and couldn't load .so files. I searched it on the internet and read many things but didn't find an answer. I tried to use System.loadLibrary("jni_latinime") but it failed again. Please give me any advice. Thanks.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.android.inputmethod.latin-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.android.inputmethod.latin-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libjni_latinime.so"
                                                                         at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:367)
                                                                         at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
                                                                         at com.android.inputmethod.latin.utils.JniUtils.<clinit>(JniUtils.java:33)
                                                                         at com.android.inputmethod.latin.utils.JniUtils.loadNativeLibrary(JniUtils.java:46)
                                                                         at com.android.inputmethod.latin.LatinIME.<clinit>(LatinIME.java:599)
                                                                         at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2877)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1437)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.Set NDK PATH**

**2.add this in build.gradle**

```
 sourceSets.main {
         jni.srcDirs = []
          jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
     }
```

**3.Create a Jni folder inside SRC direactory**

**4.Create- Android.mk--inside jni folder-**

**5.add in Android.mk file**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := "module name"//added inside system.load(); ** i used addjni**

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := Native.c   //create a native.c class
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -ljnigraphics
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**6.Create a file Application.mk---inside jni folder----------------
    and write this**

```
  APP_ABI := all
```

**7.add inside MainActivity**

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 static {
     System.loadLibrary("addjni");
 }
 TextView sum;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     sum=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.sum);
     int as=Native.sumoftwo(210,15);
     Log.e("sum",as+"");
     sum.setText(as+"");

 }
```

}

**8.create a new NativeNDK.c**

//inside jni folder and add this
     //jave_packageName_Native(Classname)_(methodname) replace(. with -)

```
 include<string.h>
 include<jni.h>
 jint JNICALL Java_droider_Native_sumoftwo(JNIEnv*  env , jclass obj,jint   a,jint b)   

      {
        jint total=(a+b);
         return total;
       }
```

**9.  go to studio terminal and inside type command**

cd app\src\main>D:\android-ndk-r10d\android-ndk-r10d\ndk-build APP_PLATFORM=android-8 enter

**10. Native.c inside main/src**

```
 public class Native {
       public native static int sumoftwo(int a,int b);
        static {
                System.loadLibrary("addjni");
        } 
    }
```

11.copy all .so from libs and paste into jinLibs if exist else create and paste

Comment: getting access denied while doing 9 step

Comment: go inside app/main if success then (location of NDK ) Like  i have in D drive , and at last paste  APP_PLATFORM=android-8

Answer (score 0):

Go to LatinIME/native/jni and build it with ndk-build..

(if it contains errors just open Android.mk and comment this line :

```
    # LOCAL_CFLAGS += -Werror -Wall -Wextra -Weffc++ -Wformat=2 -Wcast-qual -Wcast-align \
    #     -Wwrite-strings -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Winit-self -Wredundant-decls \
    #     -Woverloaded-virtual -Wsign-promo -Wno-system-headers
```

This will build jni_latinime.so file...
You can add it to your build.gradle by giving this code:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['LOCATION OF .so File']
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is "LatinIME/native/jni", are you referring to this source folder: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/master/native/jni/ ? Also, how does one access the ndk-build command?

Comment: how to build as ndk?